# Change extension of all file names containing specific string

Tags: files, rename

When I get a file whose name contains the string "x264", I wish to change its extension to ".mp4" (for reasons too detailed to explain here). Examples:

`Seinfeld_S02E05_x264.mkv`  -> `Seinfeld_S02E05_x264.mp4`

`Seinfeld_S02E05_x264.avi`  -> `Seinfeld_S02E05_x264.mp4`

What script can I use to automatically make such a change? My computer is a NAS4FREE server running FreeBSD 11.1

**UPDATE (after Jeff's response):  I forgot to mention that I want this to work in the designated directory and all its sub-directories as well. Perhaps a command rather than a script?**

Comment: **Do you know?** with this way you are losing your file `Seinfeld_S02E05_x264.mkv`? In your given sample you are rename two different files name to single name and first one will be deleted completely

Comment: I was showing the same filename twice just as an example of how I wanted the extension name changed no matter what the original extension name was.  I should have given different filenames - sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `find`:

```
find -type f -name "*x264*" -execdir sh -c 'echo mv -n "$1" "${1%.*}.mp4"' _ {} \;
```

The `-n` option will prevent `mv` to overwrite to existing files as your given samples files' name renaming to single file name and with this case you are are deleting first file.

To get this work on files without having extensions (suffix):

```
find -type f -name "*x264*" -execdir sh -c 'file="${1#./}"; 
    echo mv -n "$file" "${file%.*}.mp4"' _ {}  \;
```

remove `echo` in above to get rid of dry-run and perform rename on files.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. I was showing the same filename twice just as an example of how I wanted the extension name changed no matter what the original extension name was.  I should have given different filenames - sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

```
for f in *x264*.*
do
  mv -- "$f" "${f%.*}".mp4
done
```

The above runs a shell loop over a "glob" pattern that finds files with "x264" in their filename before some sort of extension (so that there's an extension to rename later); once it has that list of files, it calls `mv` to do the rename, and uses parameter expansion to strip the extension (period followed by anything `*`) then manually appends the `.mp4` extension.

Comment: Note that hidden files (files whose name starts with `.`) are not processed.

Comment: Indeed; seems ok for the assumed scenario. dotglob would toggle this behavior, if needed.

Comment: This will also do it for directories having x264 and dot in it's name.